# Insert Intro Jingle at Amazon Alexa with node.js

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a skill for Amazon Alexa using node.js, which plays an MP3 stream.
Now I have problems to play a jingle with a fixed URL before the stream starts.
How do I have to proceed to realize this project?

Below is the most important part of the code of the simple player:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest'
            || (Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
                && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'PlayStationIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = messages.welcome;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective("REPLACE_ALL", url, token(), 0)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options for implementing this:

- **SSML** if the jingle is very short and comply to some encodings, you may include it in the speakOutput by using [SSML and the audio tag](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio).
- **M3U** Instead of the including the URL of the stream directly in the AudioPlayerPlayDirective, you can include there the URL to an [M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), which then includes a playlist of the Jingle URL and the stream URL.
- **PlayBackNearlyFinished Intent** Just sent as first play directive the url of the Jingle and add support for the [PlayBackNearlyFinished Intent](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playbacknearlyfinished), which will be invoked by the AudioPlayer itself when playing Jingle is nearly finished and then send inside this intent an audio player play directive (without a speak) but with the URL of the stream. But be aware if that file gets nearly finished, the same PlayBackNearlyFinished Intent will get called, so you need to identify that it already has been called to avoid making an infinity loop. Best way would to use token attribute on both play commands with (first with "Jingle" and second with "Stream" or token()) so if PlayBackFinished Intent is called, check token in the request and only send the second play command, if token is "Jingle" and so identifying the Jingle has ended.

The last option would change your code to something like:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest'
            || (Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
                && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'PlayStationIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = messages.welcome;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective("REPLACE_ALL", url_jingle, "jingle", 0)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const PlayBackFinishedHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished';
    },

    handle(handlerInput) {
        if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.token === 'jingle') {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective("REPLACE_ALL", url, token(), 0)
                .getResponse();
        }
    }
};
```

Additionally you would need to activate the AudioPlayer Interface and rebuild the model afterwards, so that those controls events will reach you.

[image: Audio Player Interface activation]

Comment: Unfortunately, `PlayBackFinishedHandler` is not triggered when the jingle is over. Alexa remains silent after the jingle ends.

Comment: @Paeddy was the AudioPlayer Interface activated for the Skill and the Model re-builded afterwards (I added that step to the answer with a screenshoot where to find that setting).

Comment: yes, the AudioPlayer interface is enabled.

The single playback of `url` as well as `url_jingle` works, but not both in a row. 
Alexa executes `LaunchRequestHandler`, opens the AudioPlayer and thus exits the skill. When the jingle is now finished, the stream is terminated and Alexa considers the process as completed.
I have no option to query if the previous stream (in this case the jingle) has ended, because Alexa has already left the actual skill at the beginning of the playback.

Comment: Hi @Paeddy we are both partly right and wrong:

1. If you response with an AudioPlayer Directive you are leaving the skill. Which means no active session there.

2. But the AudioPlayer may sent your Skill AudioPlayer Interface Request. Which your skill can react.

3. I chose the wrong one. 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished' may only do clean up and not response with a new directive to play something. For that use case you need 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished' - I will update the answer.